# kivy garden Grap xmin xmax update (real time)

Tags: graph, kivy

is there a way to update xmin and xmax of Graph in kivy garden?

At the moment, my xmin is 0 and xmax is 10 and I am plotting a list containin (x,y) points. y starts from 0 and is incremented every second and x is just a counter that counts iterations. so once x is > 10 the graph is not updated in real time so the x axis does not move like e.g. 1-11 and next second 2-12 and next 3-13 etc etc so I always show 10 values but the grap is 'live'.

How to achieve it in kivy garden Graph?

```
   graph = Graph(
                    xlabel='Iteration',
                    ylabel='Value',
                    x_ticks_minor=1,
                    x_ticks_major=5,
                    y_ticks_major=1,
                    y_grid_label=True,
                    x_grid_label=True,
                    padding=5,
                    xlog=False,
                    ylog=False,
                    x_grid=True,
                    y_grid=True,
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=10,
                    ymin=0,
                    ymax=11,
                    **graph_theme)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used this flower, but try `graph.xmin = <something>`. If it doesn't work, the code probably has other name for that variable, because `xmin` in `Graph(...)` is only keyword argument. Try to look at its `__init__()` and after you see what has the value, try to access it via `graph.<variable>`. If it's not a local variable, then it should work.

However, this only says how to change it *manually*. If you have more of your code except `graph = Graph(...)`, paste it, an issue may be there. Otherwise you could try to report a glitch at garden's repo for Graph.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code found in "garden.graph" library you can call the instance of the graph to set properties of xmax, xmin, ymax and ymin.

As an example, I am seting the property of ymax to be maximum value of my data set:

```
Class Test(Widget):
    data = #list of datapoints
    graph_test = ObjectProperty(None)
    def setgraph:
        plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        self.graph_test.ymax=max(data[1])
         plot.points = [(data[0][i], data[1][i]) for i in range(0,500)]
         self.graph_test.add_plot(plot)
```

I also have a .kv file that contains the following

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
<Test>:
    graph_test : graph_test
    Graph:
        id: graph_test
        plot: MeshLinePlot
        xlabel:'X'
        ylabel:'Y'
        x_ticks_minor:1000000000000
        x_tics_major:5000000000000
        y_ticks_major:1000
        y_grid_label:True
        x_grid_label:True
        padding:5
        x_grid:True
        y_grid:True
        xmin:123413241234
        xmax:123412341234
        ymin:2000
        ymax:15000
        pos: 0, 0
        size: root.width , root.height
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I'm doing this with some Kivy Graphs and rather than resetting the XMin and XMax (which means those numbers would keep counting up for as long as the graph is running "live"), we shift the data points and leave the X range alone.

We built this simple LiveGraph class to wrap it, works nicely and is relatively performant.

```
class LiveGraph(Graph):
   def __init__(self, num_data_points=50, **kwargs):
      super(LiveGraph, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self._num_data_points = num_data_points
      self.xmin = 0
      self.xmax = num_data_points
      build_chart()

   def build_chart(self):
      plot = MeshLinePlot()

      # Initialize with empty Y values to start with
      plot.points = [(x,0) for x in range(self._num_data_points)

   # I tested a number of ways to do this - this ended up being
   # the fastest. 
   def add_point(self, point_value):
      new_points = self.plots[0].points
      new_points = [(i, new_points[i+1][1]) for i in range(self._num_data_points - 1)]
      new_points.append([len(new_points) - 1, new_value])
      self.plots[0].points = new_points
```